# CursorAdapter not showing any data in ListView

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

This is my code For activity.I have just begun to learn android.
And i am not able to get any data through the SimpleCursorAdaptor on my ListView
When I m using the ArrayAdaptor then i am able to get data on the ListView but not With Simple Cursor Adaptor

```
public class LaunchActivity extends Activity {
ListView taskList;
SQLiteDatabase db ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_launch);

    // Log.d("Anuranjit", "IN activity");
    taskList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.TaskList);
    taskList.setDividerHeight(7);

    TaskDatabaseManager taskManager = new TaskDatabaseManager(
            getApplicationContext());
    db = taskManager.getWritableDatabase();
    addData();
    Cursor c=db.rawQuery("Select * from "+TaskDatabaseManager.DATABASE_TABLE, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    String[] fromCol={TaskDatabaseManager.KEY_ROWID,TaskDatabaseManager.TASK_DESCRIPTION,TaskDatabaseManager.TASK_STATUS,TaskDatabaseManager.TASK_TIMESTAMP};
    int[] v={R.id.TaskList,R.id.TaskList,R.id.TaskList,R.id.TaskList};
        SimpleCursorAdapter sa=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,c,fromCol,v,0);

        taskList.setAdapter(sa);
}

public void addData(){
    Date c=new Date();
    db.execSQL("insert into "+TaskDatabaseManager.DATABASE_TABLE+"( "+TaskDatabaseManager.TASK_DESCRIPTION+","+TaskDatabaseManager.TASK_TIMESTAMP +","+TaskDatabaseManager.TASK_STATUS+") values ('Hello World',' "+(new Timestamp(c.getTime()))+" ' ,'0');");
    Cursor ac=db.rawQuery("Select * from "+TaskDatabaseManager.DATABASE_TABLE, null);
    ac.moveToFirst();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(ac.getCount()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ac.getString(1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

Launcher activity layout.I only have a list view in the XML is  this the problem ?

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".LaunchActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/TaskList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@android:color/holo_green_light" >
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is your problem.

```
 int[] v={R.id.TaskList,R.id.TaskList,R.id.TaskList,R.id.TaskList};
```

You have to map the values from your cursor to Textfields in your list item layout. Not in your layout that countains the list view.

Atm you are using a generic layout for your list items (android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1)
Try making your own. (simple xml layout containing 1 TextView for every value you want to display) Then:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter sa=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.my_list_item ,c,fromCol,v,0);
```

and

```
int[] v={R.id.textView1,R.id.textView2,R.id.textView3,R.id.textView4};
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer ! So should i remove my <ListView> Tag? Or should I Create A new Layout and Leave my List as it is.

Comment: No the list view has to stay. The ListView contains the list of list items and the list items have a layout on their own.